# Validate Date and Time with date in database - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to validate a form where i am updating `TimesheetEntry` Model. I want to check if `timesheet_clock_out_date` and `timesheet_clock_out_time` is not less than `timesheet_clock_in_date` and `timesheet_clock_in_time`. If yes then raise error 'Please enter proper date'. In my url i am send `primary key` of `TimesheetEntry`

urls.py

```
path('useradmin/timesheet/clock-out/<int:pk>', views.ClockOutAddView.as_view(), name='admin_timesheet_clock_out'),
```

Forms.py

```
class ClockOutForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
           model = TimesheetEntry
           fields = [
           'timesheet_clock_out_date',
           'timesheet_clock_out_time',
           ]
```

Models.py

```
class TimesheetEntry(models.Model):
       timesheet_users = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='timesheet_users')
       timesheet_clock_in_date = models.DateField()
       timesheet_clock_in_time = models.TimeField()
       timesheet_clock_out_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
       timesheet_clock_out_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Views.py

```
class ClockOutAddView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.View):

       template_name = 'admin/clock/clock_form.html'
       success_url = '/useradmin/timesheet/'

       def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
           form =  ClockOutForm(instance=TimesheetEntry.objects.get(id=pk))
           return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

       def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
           form = ClockOutForm(request.POST, instance=TimesheetEntry.objects.get(id=pk))

           if form.is_valid():

               form.save()

               return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)

           return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

How can i validate dates and time.

Comment: Validation is done by the *form*, so the `form.is_valid` will fail. That being said, I think you better use an `UpdateView` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview), and use `DateTimeField`s instead of separate `DateField` and `TimeField`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to validate a form where i am updating TimesheetEntry Model. I want to check if `timesheet_clock_out_date` and `timesheet_clock_out_time` is not less than `timesheet_clock_in_date` and `timesheet_clock_in_time`.

You can add a [**`clean(..)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean), probably here it is better to do this at the model level, that checks this.

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class TimesheetEntry(models.Model):
    timesheet_users = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='timesheet_users')
    timesheet_clock_in_date = models.DateField()
    timesheet_clock_in_time = models.TimeField()
    timesheet_clock_out_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    timesheet_clock_out_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def clean(self):
        if self.timesheet_clock_out_date is not None and self.timesheet_clock_out_time is not None:
            dt1 = datetime.combine(self.timesheet_clock_in_date, self.timesheet_clock_in_time)
            dt2 = datetime.combine(self.timesheet_clock_out_date, self.timesheet_clock_out_time)
            if dt1 > dt2:
                raise ValidationError('Please enter proper date.')
        super(TimesheetEntry, self).clean()
```

That being said, the above model is rather "weird". It is typically better to use a [**`DateTimeField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField). This will for example prevent weird situations where the `timesheet_clock_out_date` is `None`, but `timesheet_clock_out_time` is not, and vice versa.

Typically one does *not* prefix the attributes with the name of the class, since this improves the abilities of *duck* typing.

Probably a better way to model this is:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class TimesheetEntry(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='timesheet_users')
    clock_in = models.DateTimeField()
    clock_out = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def clean(self):
        if self.clock_out is not None and self.clock_in > self.clock_out:
            raise ValidationError('Please enter proper date.')
        super(TimesheetEntry, self).clean()
```

I suggest that you take a look at the [**`UpdateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview) class, since this is basically what you do here. You can pass a `form_class` to let it operate on a certain form.